# ms-rteElement not working from Azure CDN

Tags: 2013, azure, style

I've put some of our CSS and JavaScript files on Azure storage. These files are used across different websites. The problem is SharePoint seems to ignore ms-rteElement and rteStyle styles when the files are coming from a remote server. They don't appear in the ribbon.

Is it possible to use rteElement and rteStyle on a remotely hosting css file? If not, why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution we came up with is to have a local css file with just the -ms-name property.

```
/* Contact Style */
p.ms-rteElement-contact
{
    -ms-name: "Contact";
}
```